# How to replace part of string in a column, in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using oracle, toad.

I want to replace , with backspace.

Column consists of:  `bla bla foo ,CALL HELPDESK`

It has to replace:  `bla bla foo CALL HELPDESK`

Basically , should be removed

I tried like this:

```
UPDATE Mytable t
   SET column = REPLACE(t.U_MSG, ''%, CALL HELPDESK'', '% CALL HELPDESK')
```

Comment: https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-string-functions/oracle-replace/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`REPLACE` doesn't use wildcards, it simply replaces all instances of the first string with the second string. This should work:

```
UPDATE Mytable t
   SET column = REPLACE(t.U_MSG, ', CALL HELPDESK', ' CALL HELPDESK')
```

Answer (score 4):

As the replaced string is *fixed* why not simply use that:

```
UPDATE Mytable t
    SET column = SUBSTR(t.U_MSG, 1, LENGTH(t.U_MSG)-15)
--                                                  ^^
--                                    length of the replaced string
--                                    hard coded in this example, should
--                                    probably use `LENGTH(...)` for ease
--                                    of maintenance in production code
```

This is probably less clever than other solutions, but this will work even if, by unexpected twist of fate, the replaced string is present several times in some of your strings:

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT 'PLEASE, CALL HELPDESK' U_MSG FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL SELECT 'CALL HELPDESK, CALL HELPDESK! THEY SAID, CALL HELPDESK' FROM DUAL
)

SELECT SUBSTR(t.U_MSG, 1, LENGTH(t.U_MSG)-15) || ' CALL HELP DESK' MSG FROM t;
```

Producing:

```
MSG
------------------------------------------------------
PLEASE CALL HELP DESK
CALL HELPDESK, CALL HELPDESK! THEY SAID CALL HELP DESK
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering **not** to replace **ALL** commas..

```
UPDATE Mytable t
   SET column = REGEXP_REPLACE(t.U_MSG,',( )*(CALL HELPDESK)','CALL HELPDESK')
```

Else, Simply

```
UPDATE Mytable t
   SET column = REGEXP_REPLACE(t.U_MSG,',( )*')
```

Note, It removes all spaces after comma as well.